# How can I use existing Zend config.ini in a standalone php script?

Tags: php, zend-framework

A client wants me to create a standalone php script, which needs to

- connect to the database of their existing web app and run a SQL query
- then send an email based on the results of the query.

The clients web app uses Zend framework version 1.10.
I would like my script to be able to access the database and SMTP connection details contained within the zend framework `/application/configs/application.ini` config file so that the client doesnt have to re-enter the SMTP and DB connection info once I give them the finished script.

How can I access the config details contained in `/application/configs/application.ini` in my script?

Comment: You could use [`parse_ini_file()`](http://php.net/manual/function.parse-ini-file.php) or just bite the bullet and include the relevant sections of `Zend_Config`. I don't think there's many dependencies on other framework elements

Comment: Yup, pretty much looks like you just need `Zend/Config.php`, `Zend/Exception.php` and the `Zend/Config/Ini.php`. Files here ~ http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/tags/release-1.10.0/library/Zend/

Comment: Can you please answer the question if that solution worked?

Comment: @M.M. have provided an answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm wouldn't say this is a definitive solution, I'm just providing info about my findings in case its useful to others who come across this post.

Using the `parse_ini_file()` function on the  `xxx.ini` file definitely works and is the current "working solution" I am using.
However `parse_ini_file()` only enables access to basic config parameters, so I'm currently trying to see if I can get hooked deeper into the init code, to utilise more of the applications pre-written code.

Of note, the bootstrap process creates a `$config` object from Zends [Zend_Config_ini](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/zend.config.adapters.ini.html) class but this uses `parse_ini_file()` itself so doesn't offer anything extra - other than the main application having a dependency on it - and adds more complexity i.e. its has its own dependencies like the [Zend autoloader](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.10/en/learning.autoloading.intro.html).

So, so far for me it is easier to use the `parse_ini_file()` function, rather than try and setup a zend `$config` object especially considering that, whilst the old version 1.10 of Zend framework is documented, it doesnt have any indexing which makes it harder to use.